# how to get file name when file is imported using pandas.read_csv

Tags: pandas, csv, filenames

I am writing big function, I need to use input file name for the purpose of giving out output file name. I tried something

```
import pandas as pd
import os
input_file = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv',header=None)
input_file_name = os.basename(input_file)
```

but I can't get back file name.
How can I retrieve 'my_file' here?

Answer (score 0):

```
def do_job(input_file):
    if not os.path.exists(input_file):
        sys.stderr.write("Error: '%s' does not exist"%input_file)
        sys.exit(1)
    input = pd.read_csv(input_file,header=None)

    # do many operations

    # so file name is stored in handle 'input_file'
    # I can give output file name using input_file
    output_name = 'Results_' + input_file
```